# how to create a double foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have to create a table how's structure is

```
create table reparto
(
numrep integer,
nomespec varchar(20),
nomeosp varchar(20),
cittaosp varchar(25),
primary key (numrep,nomespec,nomeosp,cittaosp),
foreign key(nomeosp,cittaosp) references ospedale(nomeosp,cittaosp),
foreign key nomespec references specializzazione(nomeospe)
);
```

of course I've already create the tables

```
create table ospedale
(
nomeosp varchar(20),
cittaosp varchar(25),
numasl integer,
idasp varchar(4),
primary key(nomeosp,cittaosp)
);
```

and

```
create table specializzazione
(
nomespe varchar (20) primary key
);
```

of course it doesn't work and I don't know what to do, can someone tell me how to create several differentsforeign key?

Comment: First, is this MySQL or SQL-Server, because the syntax may be different.

Comment: is MySQL.... I looked everywhere but I can't find a solution

Comment: You say it doesn't work. Why doesn't it? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few obvious things we can point out here. The column name given in the foreign key definition:

```
references specializzazione(nomeospe)
                                ^
```

Doesn't match the column name in the table definition

```
... specializzazione ( nomespe ...
                       ^^^^^^^
```

And the column list for the foreign key should be enclosed in parens

```
... foreign key (nomespec)
                ^        ^
```

Comment: I feel so dumb right now xD I swear i read it so many times and I try with all kind of combination and I didn't notice that stupid error -.-" thamk you so muh anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some literal error and incorect order creating tables please check this:

```
create table specializzazione
(
nomespe varchar (20) primary key
);

create table ospedale
(
nomeosp varchar(20),
cittaosp varchar(25),
numasl integer,
idasp varchar(4),
primary key(nomeosp,cittaosp)
);

create table reparto
(
numrep integer,
nomespec varchar(20),
nomeosp varchar(20),
cittaosp varchar(25),
primary key (numrep,nomespec,nomeosp,cittaosp),
foreign key(nomeosp,cittaosp) references ospedale(nomeosp,cittaosp),
foreign key (nomespec) references specializzazione(nomespe)
);
```